# vim help produces "unable to open swap file" error

Tags: vim

In vim, frequently when I perform a ':help ' command, I get an error. Here's an error I see when I perform ':help tags' for example:

```
"tagsrch.txt.gz" [readonly][noeol] 42L, 11288C
Error detected while processing function gzip#read:
line   51:
E303: Unable to open swap file for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/tagsrch.txt.gz", recovery impossible
41 fewer lines
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I press enter, the help comes up as desired, but this is still a nuisance. What have I done wrong? My google-foo is apparently too weak for this because I don't see other people complaining about this.

Is this because I have this set for my swap directory?

```
set directory=~/.vim/swap,.
```

Let me know if it would be helpful to paste my entire vimrc. I'm on rhel7 with vim 7.4, in case it's helpful.

Here's my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" vim:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:et
" Tab preferences
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set expandtab

execute pathogen#infect()

" Where to store swap files.  By default, they will go into ~/.vim/swap, but
" if that doesn't work, they will go in cwd.
set directory=~/.vim/swap,.

filetype plugin indent on   " enables filetype indent specific plugins

" Instructions on how to tab complete filenames.
" set wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildmode=longest,list
set wildmenu

" In case there are vim modelines at the top of the file, as there
" is with this one.
set modeline

" Always show the status line.
set laststatus=2

" Look for a tags file.
set tags=./tags,tags;
" Also search for .git/tags files.
set tags^=./.git/tags,*/.git/tags;~

" Make Ctrl-] show the list of options by default.
nnoremap <C-]> g<C-]>
nnoremap <C-w><C-]> <C-w>g<C-]>

" Colors
" Have syntax highlighting in terminals which can display colours:
if has('syntax') && (&t_Co > 2)
  syntax on
else
  syntax off
endif
set background=dark
set hlsearch
set incsearch

" I so often type teh instead of the.
abbreviate teh the

" To help vim deal with pasting text
:map <F9> :set invpaste <CR>
set pt=<F9>

" Toggle vim's spell checker with <F5>
:map <F5> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<cr>

" Shortcuts for c code.
map! ,bc /*  */^[hhi
map! ,bz #if 0^M#endif /* 0 */^[O

" Ignore whitespace when diffing files.
map ,iw :set diffopt+=iwhite<CR>
set path^=/home/bneradt/work/trafficserver/**
```

Comment: What are the permissions on those directories? Can you `touch` a file into both directories?

Comment: In either case, you shouldn't be trying to edit help files, that's not the default for `:help`. It might be beneficial paste your `vimrc`; do you do something that sets `modifiable` or `ma` on everything you open?

Comment: @jeremysprofile: Thanks for the reply. I do not have write permissions to anything in /usr/share. But I wouldn't expect to have write permissions there since I'm a non-root user. I posted my ~/.vimrc.

Comment: Nothing stands out to me. You can try `vim -u NONE` and then opening a help file to see if the problem persists; if not, it's definitely something in your `vimrc` and you can try commenting out sections to figure out what line causes the problem. If the problem is still there with `vim -u NONE`... I have no idea. I'd give up and upgrade vim, probably.

Comment: I will say that `set directory=~/.vim/swap,.` in my vimrc doesn't cause me issues with opening help files.

Comment: Can you try two things separately and see if it still happens in either case? `set directory=.`,  and `set noswf`.

Comment: Another thing curious I noticed is in my vim(8.1) `runtime/doc/tagsrch.txt` is not gzipped. I also checked vim74 source code and it's not gzipped there either. How did yours become a gz file?

Comment: @jingx I’ve seen that with vim.tiny or similar. What’s curious to me is the editing—try it without the pathogen line (maybe it’s a plugin)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation / partition is full. Cleaned it and it works now.